# RMI - do I get it right?

Tags: java, rmi

Can someone verify if i understand java RMI correctly?

If I had:

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject 
{
    public Server() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        try
        {
            Naming.rebind("rmi://someAddress/someName" , this);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (ConnectException ex)
        {
        }

/* do sometnig else there */
   }
}
```

would that mean that if 100 clients connect, RMI would create 100 copies of this server as threads to facilitate those clients (without my further intervention)?

Comment: Is this an academical question? Or what problem do you want to solve? RMI is quite low-level. If you want to use RMI based technology in a project consider using EJB 3.x (Java EE 5/6). The application server will solve a lot of issues for you.

Comment: Well I kinda started in RMI and I'm afraid it might be to late to change but thx this tip.

Comment: Well, EJB is build on RMI so you could reuse a lot of stuff. Working with RMI directly requires you to make sure the right things are thread-safe, which is non-trivial and will probably cost you more than switching to EJB. When working with EJBs and following some simple principles many of these threading issues are taken care for you. And you can profit from all the other parts of the Java EE stack, which again will probably safe you more than the switch to Java EE will cost you. Except if this is a very small exercise project.

Comment: Hmm, for me it is rather big. Plus seeing specs for EJB being 500+ pages long I might not have enough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if 100 clients connected, the RMI registry would manage a number of separate threads which all executed against that single instance of your `Server` class.

Most likely, a new thread would be spawned for each client connection, possibly multiple threads, but a new instance of `Server` would never be created.

Comment: So if a client connects a I have to create new server thread and rebind it with different name to process each client requests?

Comment: @oO: No, this is done for you. Just make sure the `Server` class is thread-safe. You don't need to manage instances or threads yourself.

Comment: Just one more: If my server would only connect to mysql and with the connected client then it should be thread safe?

Comment: The RMI Registry doesn't manage threads at all. It doesn't participate in RMI beyond the bind/lookup phase. @oO. No. Any required synchronization is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

> would that mean that if 100 clients connect, RMI would create 100 copies of this server as threads to facilitate those clients (without my further intervention)?

There is no  such thing as 'create 100 copies of this server as threads'. *You* create any instances of the server, and RMI creates as many threads as it needs to call your server's methods. Any synchronization required in your server is up to you.